# Real time communication between Python and an App, Website or Email

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to create real time communication between Python (on my PC) and an App, Website or Email, its like I choose different parameters with the App or Website and then these parameters sends to Python, Python do some calculations and after sends the result back to the App or the Web or Email. What is the best (easiest) way to do that? I just need some tips about which libraries and tools do I need to do that.

I did some research in internet and I got lost in how many ways are there to accomplish that.

Comment: I think a Diagramm would help to understand what you try to achieve. Also it would be good to see some code you tried out already that might be improved

Answer (score 1):

If you run your server on one of the big cloud companies they will probably have some api to talk with IoT devices such as your laptop.

AWS for example has the [AWS IoT SDK for Python](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python). See this [Example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-plant-watering.html) for more Information. (Not promoting AWS, Microsoft/Google offer similar stuff)

You might also get inspiration from those SDKs on how you could build your own solution